# Running shell script as a part of spark job

Tags: java, scala, shell, hadoop, apache-spark

I am submitting a sparkjob using spark submit which contains execution of a shell script.
I have written the logic for script execution as :

```
 val paraname = encFile.substring(0,encFile.length()-4)
     val pb = new ProcessBuilder("/home/roswal01/gpghdfs.sh",paraname)
     val p : Process = pb.start()
```

But when I run this through my spark-job it gives me an error of

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: where's that shell script stored at?

Comment: @DavidSchuler on my unix home

Comment: if you're using HDFS, but that script somewhere into HDFS and try referencing it from there instead

Comment: @DavidSchuler tried that as well gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the executable attribute is not set on the bash file, e.g.

```
chmod +x /home/roswal01/gpghdfs.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer. It’s because of helpful peers like yourself that we’re able to learn together as a community. Here are a few tips on how to make your answer great: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).